# Getting double array when using Doctrine dump utility with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Im getting a double print value when using Doctrine dump utility like:

```
exit(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($array));

exit(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump("Hello World"));
```

This is an example of what Im getting when using it:

```
string(10) "hola mundo" string(10) "hola mundo"
```

Or for an array, would be this

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "RED"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "GREEN"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "BLUE"
}
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "RED"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "GREEN"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "BLUE"
}
```

This is happening to me in every controller Im using. Apart from this, everything works well but I have other projects and this isnt working like this. Im using 2.6.11 version of sf.

Any idea how to solve this behavior?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Why are you using this dump function ? Symfony2 already has a dump function and you don't have to FQCN., just `exit(dump($array));` (in dev mode of course)

Comment: Hey thanks @COil . For me the way it worked was ```exit(var_dump($array));``` . Didn't know this approach.

Comment: Well var_dump() is the native PHP function and it doesn't handle complex Doctrine objects, get a look at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

**For further reference:**

Function *dump()* defined in Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug.php looks as fallow:

```
public static function dump($var, $maxDepth = 2, $stripTags = true, $echo = true) {
...
}
```

You can call it like this *dump($your_variable, 2, true, false)* and you should get single result, basically you just have to override default parameters.